# What does a tilde (~) in front of a single variable mean (facet_wrap)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am going through Hadley Wickham's "R for Data Science" where he uses `~var` in ggplot calls.

I understand `y ~ a + bx`, where `~` describes a formula/relationship between dependent and independent variables, but what does `~var` mean? More importantly, why can't you just put the variable itself? See code below:

```
ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  facet_wrap(~ class, nrow = 2)
```

or

```
demo <- tribble(
  ~cut,         ~freq,
  "Fair",       1610,
  "Good",       4906,
  "Very Good",  12082,
  "Premium",    13791,
  "Ideal",      21551
)

ggplot(data = demo) +
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = cut, y = freq), stat = "identity")
```

Comment: In case of the `tribble` function, formulas are used to distinguish column names from character data. This can be seen in [extract_frame_names_from_dots implementation](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/blob/9c2463e30c3cfdad562808ebc093c733235f70b4/R/tribble.R#L85).

Answer (score 5):

It is a syntax specific to `facet_wrap`, where a formula can be given as the input for the variable relationships. [From the documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html#arguments) for the first argument, `facets`:

> A set of variables or expressions quoted by vars() and
>   defining faceting groups on the rows or columns dimension. The
>   variables can be named (the names are passed to labeller). For
>   compatibility with the classic interface, can also be a formula or
>   character vector. Use either a one sided formula, '~a b, or a
>   character vector,c("a", "b")'.

So I think you can now just give the variable names without the tilde, but you used to need to give a one-sided formula with the tilde.

Comment: Can you explain what a one-sided formula is?

Comment: A formula is created with the `~`. A one-sided formula has only variables on one side, like  your example ~ class. These functions just choose to accept their input in this form, it doesn't imply any actual equation like its use in lm. It does not have a specifc meaning, it just means that the variables are related but the function can choose what that relation means.

Comment: "So I think you can now just give the variable names without the tilde," ...but I wonder how... I get this error:`Error: tribble() needs to specify at least one column using the ~name syntax.`

Comment: @TheRedPea That quotation was referring to `facet_wrap` specifically, not `tribble` which still needs you to use `~` for the column names

Answer (score 5):

It's just `ggplot` making use of the `formula` structure to let the user decide what variables to facet on. From `?facet_grid`:

> For compatibility with the classic interface, rows can also be a formula with the rows (of the tabular display) on the LHS and the columns (of the tabular display) on the RHS; the dot in the formula is used to indicate there should be no faceting on this dimension (either row or column).

So `facet_grid(. ~ var)` just means to facet the grid on the variable `var`, with the facets spread over columns. It's the same as `facet_grid(col = vars(var))`.

Despite looking like a `formula`, it's not really being used as a formula: it's just a way to present multiple arguments to R in a way that the `facet_grid` code can clearly and unambiguously interpret.

Answer (score 0):

To understand the **why** part of your question, look at how the tilde is used in plotting.

```
lattice::xyplot(mpg ~ disp, data=mtcars)
```

This gives `disp` as the x axis (independent variable) and `mpg` as the y axis (dependent variable). By analogy, facet_wrap() is taking the RHS of the ~ as the columns to facet by (ie. the horizontal/x/independent variable) and the LHS as the rows to facet by (vertical/y/dependent variable). If you only give a RHS of the ~, you are only giving the columns (as noted above this is equivalent to `facet_grid(col = vars(var))`).